# Seaborn scatterplot shows wrong value in legend despite setting a max value in hue_norm

Tags: seaborn, legend, scatter-plot, hue

I want to have the seaborn scatterplot legend show different colours from 0 to 130, but instead it shows 50, 100 and 150. The max value in my dataset is 130, so it is very confusing to the reader to see 150.

Can I not make it use ranges instead of numbers? And how do I know which numbers are included in colour for 50 (Is it everything up to 50?)?

```
Nplot130317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", hue_norm=(0,130), data=Ndata130317, s=2, linewidth=0)
```

[image: Scatterplot]